# How to write generic methods for all controllers in angualrjs?

Tags: angularjs

I try to clear my project from code duplicate and wonder if I can reduce followed logic.

I have goolge maps as directive and directive notifies a controller about some events.

This method verifies if we run in digest cycle and returns `true/false` respectively.

```
var isScopeInCycle = function(){
      return $scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest';
  }
```

However I'm interesting to use this method in several controllers.

I thought to put it on service but service is singleton and I can't use `$scope` there.

Here is example:

**controller**

```
 ....

 var isScopeInCycle = function(){
      return $scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest';
  }


$scope.zoomChanged = function(){ 
            if (isScopeInCycle()) {
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                   /* .. */;                    
                });
            }            
        }

        $scope.idle = function(){ 
            if (isScopeInCycle()) {
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    /* .. */;   
                });
            }            
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$rootScope` in a service.

```
module.factory('utils', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        isScopeInCycle: function () {
            return $rootScope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $rootScope.$root.$$phase != '$digest';
        }
    };
});
```

And then in your controllers just inject `utils`.

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'utils', function ($scope, utils) {
    $scope.zoomChanged = function(){ 
        if (utils.isScopeInCycle()) {
            $scope.$apply(function(){
               /* .. */;                    
            });
        }            
    }
}]);
```

You could also put the `$scope.$apply` code in the service if you want to get rid of even more code duplication.

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to accomplish this.
One way is to add this method to the $rootScope using the `run` method:

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.isScopeInCycle = function() { 
        return $rootScope.$$phase != '$apply' && $rootScope.$$phase != '$digest';
    }
});
```

Another way is to use a service as you wrote in the original post, but to pass the $scope as an argument to the function.

```
var isScopeInCycle = function($scope){
    return $scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest';
}

...
$scope.zoomChanged = function(){ 
    if (isScopeInCycle($scope)) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            /* .. */;                    
        });
    }            
}
```